# suddenly lost host routing on ubuntu server

Tags: networking, server, routing

i have ubuntu 14.04 server, which installed as a web server. the server also has 35 routing entry. sometimes the server suddenly lost connection to one or two another server, which routing entry has define in routing tables.

i don't know what happen with my server, even i cannot find the log for trace the problem. can somebody help me? i think, it's very weird problem. even the log file, i cannot found. :(

my server:
ubuntu 14.04
cpu: 1
mem: 4 gb
vm/phisycal: virtual machine

Comment: By routing, do you mean iptable entries?

Comment: No.. Routing table. route add -net/-host command

Comment: @banganto: Did you lost the entries upon reboot or while running?

Comment: in running system, and i had put "route add" command in "/etc/network/interfaces".. what should i do, if i want to show the activity of routing table or network interface, and then put that on log file.

Answer (score 0):

Just like `iptable` rules, `route` rules are not saved / reloaded on reboot (meaning they don't survive reboots unless you save / reload them).

Please see this [link](http://linux.cloudibee.com/2009/05/configuring-persistent-static-route-in-linux/) for more details.